# StaleElementReferenceError when clicking on 2 different divs to unselect them

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a website using `Selenium` and `NodeJS` and one of the actions I want to perform is to unselect all the elements of a div made as a select and leave only one of them selected but I am encountering the following issue:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (E:\ProyectosDesarrollo\Biability\aena-dti\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:517:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (E:\ProyectosDesarrollo\Biability\aena-dti\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:642:13)
    at Executor.execute (E:\ProyectosDesarrollo\Biability\aena-dti\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:568:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (E:\ProyectosDesarrollo\Biability\aena-dti\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:731:17)
```

I've read all the posts about it and I am not able to make it work properly. I am totally sure the element hasn't disappeared from the DOM so it must have been deattached but I don't know how to locate it again.

I even tried with `elementLocated()` but it didn't work.

This is the problematic function:

```
function selectMonth(){
    // Click on the element for months
    driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr342"]/div')).click();

    // Dropdown with the months
    const selectMonth = by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr346"]/div/div/div');
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(selectMonth)).then(
        () => {
            // Select the desired month
            driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr346"]/div/div/div[3]')).click();

            // const elementMonth = by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr346"]/div/div/div[4]');
            // driver.wait(until.elementLocated(selectMonth)).then(
            //     () => {
            //         console.log('Here')
            //         driver.findElement(elementMonth).click();
            //     }
            // );

            driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr346"]/div/div/div[4]')).click();
            // driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr346"]/div/div/div[5]')).click();
            // Click on ok
            driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="mstr348"]/div')).click();
        }
    );
}
```

My guess is there must be a Javascript function executing in the website when I click one of the elements which is causing the 2nd element to not be attached to the DOM but I haven't found a proper way to handler this with `Javascript`

Comment: use webdriverwaits.  You aren't waiting after the click() is used.  You may need to catch Stale Element exceptions and deal with them.  (If the DOM is still updating... your webelement reference will be off... so stale.)

Comment: I tried by waiting for the element to be located. You can see the code commented out. That's another way of trying to do it.

Comment: You should wait for expected condition of "toBeClickable"... since you're clicking.  It'll check for various things including clickability.

Comment: I've just tried to find a condition for `until` that makes a reference to the element being clickable and it doesn't show anything for js library.

Comment: can you share the url or html?